# Moving server Share Points to a new drive in Mac OS X Server 10.8

Tags: macos, server.app

How do I move a Share Point under Mac OS X 10.8 so that it points to a folder on a different volume?

I have currently have 8 Share Points located on an old external RAID. I am upgrading to a new RAID. I have copied my files over to the new RAID. Now I need to tell Mac OS X Server that the Share Points should use folders found on the new RAID. I don't see any way of re-targeting the Share Points.

I seem to remember that older versions of OS X Server, allowed you to so re-target the Share Point to a different folder. Clients would be disconnected and have to reconnect to the server, but would not notice any change.

Answer (score 2):

Its still possible, see [OS X Server: Changing the service data storage location](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202333)
:

> In OS X Server (Mountain Lion) and Lion Server v10.7.2 or later, you can store service data in a location other than your startup volume.
>
> To change the service data storage volume:
>
> - Open Server app, and connect to the desired server.
> - Select the name of the server in the column on the left under the heading Server (on OS X Mountain Lion) or Hardware (on OS X Lion).
> - Click the Settings tab.
> - Click the Edit… button on the "Service Data" line.
> - Select a volume.